# Hide block of text if there are no items to compare

Tags: php, magento-2.2.5

I'd like to display/hide a block of text by wrapping in a PHP IF Statement. Value will be based on whether **Comparable Products is not equal to "0" (or NULL?)**. I imagine I'd be looking at something like:

`app/design/frontend/Theme/theme_child/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/compare/link.phtml`

```
<?php if ($INSERT_ANSWER()): ?>
    <p>You have products to compare</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- Leave blank -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'd probably need to include a Helper as well.

Comment: Do you have the location of the file where you will perform that above action ?

Comment: It's a child theme file. But technically, the solution could be implemented in any phtml file in any location.

Comment: Ok, so you need the code to count of comparable products right ?

Comment: Just to compare if the amount of products currently being compared is equal to "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the below to any of your phtml:

```
<?php $count = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getItemCollection()->count(); ?>
<?php if ($count > 0): ?>
    <p>You have products to compare</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- Leave blank -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```
<?php $collection = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getItemCollection(); ?>
    <?php if (count($collection) > 0): ?>
        <p>You have products to compare</p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <!-- Leave blank -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm after. But when I try to echo `$count`, it always results in "0".

Comment: You can try count($collection) instead of ->count()

Comment: That results in `Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable`

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code as below to get the count of comparable products in your customer account:

```
protected $compare;

public function __construct (
......
Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare $compare
......
)
{
    $this->compare = $compare;
}

//use as below in your code:

$this->compare->getItemCollection()->count();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement your solution without causing errors.

Comment: Are you trying to implement the code in a template file ?